# Stacking over input panels in Netbeans WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, awt

I'm trying to put a JButton in the WYSIWYG GUI editor in Netbeans at the center of a wheel of buttons I made around an input panel.  The input panel is hidden in the program (specified by a user in an XML file) and the JButton should just be at the center of the wheel.  I can't figure out how to do that because actually putting it in on top of the input panel in the WYSIWYG editor just puts it in the input panel and it is therefore hidden when when the code is executed.  Is it possible to view the "layers" in the editor and put the button in "under" the input panel so that it won't be hidden along with the panel?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew Thompson.  I'm actually at work editing 7 years of legacy code.  If I had a choice, I would not be using this option.

Comment: I'm in school working for one of the departments.  Trust that my other duties at this job will look very good on a CV and the connections will help me get an assistantship in graduate school.  I'm not at a professional point in my career where I can just "resign" without suffering a major setback.

Comment: .. Personally, if in your position, I'd code it up using JSE then present it to my boss with the general prefix.. "Well, I was playing with a hand coded version to make sure I got the concept before trying it in the designer, can you have a look over it and confirm it is the right layout?" - I'd be surprised if the boss did not come back with "forget doing it in the designer, if it works, uses it".

Comment: I just had to modify gridbag constraints to place it manually after hiding the input panel.  I'll look into the JSE thing tonight because working with this editor is a nightmare.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer. :)

Comment: Embarrassing question:  how?  I don't see the option that's normally there.

Comment: Umm.. perhaps they removed the 'answer your own question' for low rep. users until a time limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only effective solution I could find was to modify a gridbag constraints object and manually insert the button in the code after the panel was hidden at runtime.